# What are the definitions for a queue in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue

I have some code for a stack which looks like this:

```
class Stack():

  def init(self):
    self.items = []

  def isEmpty(self):
    return self.items == []

  def push(self, item):
    return self.items.append(item)

  def pop(self):
    return self.items.pop()

  def getElements(self):
    return self.items
```

What would the equivalent be for a queue?

Comment: What is the main difference between a stack and a queue?

Comment: I would say a stack is last-in-first-out and a queue is first-in-first-out?

Comment: `pop/pull: del self.items[0]`, but using a list as underlying data structure makes either pull or offer O(n)

Comment: @Altoyr Exactly :-) I thought OP might think and answer that :D

Comment: @thefourtheye ah damn, I thought you were serious :)

Answer (score 1):

A Queue is First-In-First-Out and it is really easy to do this.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        return self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def get_elements(self):
        return self.items

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        return self.items.append(item)

    def pull(self):
        return self.items.pop(0)

    def get_elements(self):
        return self.items

stack = Stack() # items = []
stack.push("A") # items = ["A"]
stack.push("B") # items = ["A", "B"]
stack.push("C") # items = ["A", "B", "C"]
stack.pop() # items = ["A", "B"]

queue = Queue() # items = []
queue.push("A") # items = ["A"]
queue.push("B") # items = ["A", "B"]
queue.push("C") # items = ["A", "B", "C"]
queue.pull() #items = ["B", "C"]
```

Comment: Thanks, this has really helped me in my computer science class.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Python like Java, defining classes for such basic ADTs is not "Pythonic", not to mention it goes against performance due to extra wrapping.

The built-in lists can do that and much more.

A Stack is LIFO (Last In First Out)

[Using Lists as Stacks](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks)

```
>>> stack = []

# push, use append
>>> stack.append(1)
>>> stack.append(2)
>>> stack.append(3)

# pop
>>> stack.pop() # to get the last inserted element
>>>
3

# isEmpty
>>> if stack:
>>>     print('not empty')
```

A Queue is FIFO (First In First Out)

[Using Lists as Queues](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-queues)

```
>>> queue = collections.deque()

# push, use append
>>> queue.append(1)
>>> queue.append(2)
>>> queue.append(3)

# pull, use popleft to get the "first" inserted element
>>> queue.popleft()
>>>
1
```

Comment: I don't really care about what is considered 'Pythonic'. I just want functioning code

Comment: @10FG Sorry I thought you were trying to use this code in real world software (with performance considerations), for CS they pretty much require the Javified version. Anyway, keep in mind that is for teaching you data structures, real world usage may change.